# Allowing negative values up to a specific value

Tags: mariadb, schema

I have a situation where we store the value of credits a user has in the database:

`` `credits` DOUBLE(22,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00', ``

The credits are numbers going from 1 to any positive value. But now there is a situation where we want to deduct credits monthly from users, and I see a situation where users may have 0 credits at the time of the SQL query.

What are the best practices to handle this? I know that allowing negative numbers can create lots of bugs and exploits but we really need to implement something this

So example: Every last day of month we will  deduct -1 credit from all users. I use mariadb 10.6.11 but can upgrade to a later version if that helps

Comment: Illogical. If "credits are numbers going from 1 to any positive value" then `DEFAULT '0.00'` is at least strange. *What are the best practices to handle this?* Define this column as SIGNED. and add according CHECK constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to prevent values below a certain negative value, then you could use a check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT credits_greater CHECK (credits >= -1.0);
```

And if you try to insert a value below, it fails the check and throws an error:

```
MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO your_table(id, credits) VALUES (1, -1.1);
ERROR 4025 (23000): CONSTRAINT `credits_greater` failed for `test`.`your_table`
```

You could write a trigger to do something similar, or write a
trigger to dynamically fix the value being inserted or updated. However, I would argue that it's best practice to use a check constraint whenever that is an option rather than using a trigger. Then let your application handle any errors thrown from the database system whenever a user attempts to violate the constraint.

Triggers have some limitations and are also seen by some as maintenance nightmares. See also [MariaDB's list of trigger limitations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/trigger-limitations/).

Comment: Should I use strict mode ? It seems like a good practice to avoid bugs, and have predictable behavior unless I'm understanding it wrong, and is it possible to have it only for credits?

Comment: @Freedo I would definitely recommend strict mode. Otherwise you might end up with lost data (e.g. not enough space for storing a string in a varchar column) as only a warning is thrown which applications will typically ignore, so you will never notice. You can't set it just for one column, though. But sql_mode is a session variable, so it's possible to set it for only certain sessions, and then have the global sql_mode be more relaxed. Although I would recommend using strict everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE ...
    SET foo = GREATEST(foo - 1, -10.00)
```

This decrements `foo` by 1 but prevents the result from going below -10.  (Maybe this trivial code is what you are looking for?)  (`LEAST()` is the counterpart to that.)

Do not use `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` if you want storage and rounding to 2 decimal places.  Instead, use `DECIMAL(11,2)` to, for example, allow values up to a billion and with 2 decimal places.  (As with `DOUBLE`, `DECIMAL` is "signed".)

As for controlling limits -- that needs an application solution, not a database solution.  However, see `TRIGGER` and/or `STORED PROCEDURE` as ways to encapsulate *your* business logic in SQL.

> Every last day of month we will deduct -1 credit from all users

That `UPDATE` is possible, but it will be painfully slow if you have a billion users.  (If you need to discuss that, write a Question focusing just on that.)

Comment: I don't care about the performance of the UPDATE, as it can take a few hours to run no issue. I'm just trying to avoid bugs and exploits being possible because negative values are allowed

Comment: And right now users do use fractions of credits... = a value of 0.5 or 1.5 or etc is allowed, i think that's why we were using double

Comment: Can't constraints be used instead of triggers ?

Comment: @Freedo - Do you want the query to fail?  Or to "fix" the value?

Comment: @Freedo - `DECIMAL` has no roundoff error; `DOUBLE` may.  (`INT` is out of the question since it does not lake fractions at all.)

Comment: I think that `CHECK` constraints seem like a sensible solution if you're looking to provide a "debug assertion" of sorts that prevents you from accidentally going negative. For automatically fixing it, triggers do seem like the correct approach.

Comment: I want the query to set the value to negative if needed, which I'll believe it will never be more than -1 or -0.5 I think? But not allow the value to be lower than that, to prevent any exploit or bugs... and I also worry about application logic that was made with never negative credits in mind

Comment: What is the performance difference between a constraint and a trigger?

Comment: @Freedo If choosing between a constraint and a trigger, I would say a constraint is best practice for this type of problem. As for performance, I don't know, but a constraint is at least unlikely to be slower than a trigger.

Comment: @markusjm and/or dbdemon -- Provide an Answer rather than hiding in Comments.